# Jawbone API integration with our health wealness app not returns data

Tags: jawbone

We have integrated Jawbone web API with our health tracker app.

We are using the device, Jawbone UP 24 for our testing.

The Connect part has been working well from our App. But the syncing always return empty response as below.

data response {"meta":{"user_xid":"RCLWx75WGKTdnY0L4UyFZg","message":"OK","code":200,"time":1464848584},"data":{"items":[],"size":0}}

Jawbone User Access token sent in header :

Je5CDuGC9OSc-05UAifnK9kVk6thTRHewCwuwXuPuTo7mW7qLWnnd2I4ljqtCw-RlXB3v78Ji6VXW2MSxp0B_VECdgRlo_GULMgGZS0EumxrKbZFiOmnmAPChBPDZ5JP

StepRequest URL:

https://jawbone.com/nudge/api/v.1.1/users/@me/moves?start_time=1464796800000&end_time=1464848584617

We follow the steps as per the document in this link - https://jawbone.com/up/developer/.

We are worried that it's not working because the API supports only the new devices (Jawbone UP 2, 3 and 4) not for the Jawbone UP 24.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your start_time and end_time are in milliseconds whereas they should be seconds.

This request should get the step data you're looking for:
https://jawbone.com/nudge/api/v.1.1/users/@me/moves?start_time=1464796800.000&end_time=1464848584.617

Here's the definition of start_time and end_time from the [documentation for the moves endpoint](https://jawbone.com/up/developer/endpoints/moves):

[image: start_time int To be used along with end_time. Epoch timestamp that denotes the start of the time range queried for move events. end_time int To be used with start_time. Epoch timestamp that denotes the end of the time range queried for move events.]

And the [Wikipedia page for Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) defines Epoch time as:

> Unix time (also known as POSIX time or Epoch time) is a system for
>   describing instants in time, defined as the number of **seconds** that
>   have elapsed since. . .